# Using @MockBean always returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the @MockBean annotation in Spring Boot 2.3.0. "user" always returns even though Mockito should have cought the function getCurrentUser.

```
    @MockBean   private AuthService authService;

    private User mockUser;

    @Test
        public void test() {

            Mockito.when(authService.getCurrentUser()).thenReturn(mockUser);
            User userTest = new User();
            mockUser = userTest;
            User user =authService.getCurrentUser();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you do the `thenReturn(mockUser)` before  `new User();` The correct code would be something like:

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        User userTest = new User();
        mockUser = userTest;
        Mockito.when(authService.getCurrentUser()).thenReturn(mockUser);
        User user = authService.getCurrentUser();
    }
```

Also, you don't need  `User userTest = new User();` You can do  `mockUser = new User();`